# How to install glassfish beside apache centos 6

Tags: apache, glassfish, centos6

How to install glassfish beside apache centos 6 , that I can specify domain for apache and another to glassfish

Answer (score 0):

In glassfish, you can modify the ports used by the `http-listeners` and by the admin console in the file `glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml` (search for http-listeners).

For the domain names, you can either search for `domain-name` in the same file or do it through the admin console: Configuration --> Virtual Servers --> Your server's name.
Finally, using the asadmin tool:

```
asadmin set server-config.jms-service.jms-host.default_JMS_host.host="0.0.0.0"
asadmin set server-config.jms-service.jms-host.default_JMS_host.host="hostname"
```

be sure to restart the domain after changes (`asadmin restart-domain`)

Comment: can I Do this solution ? in apache 

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/" 
 ServerName SITENAME.com
 
 <Proxy balancer://glassfish>
  BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8009 route=glassfish
  
 </Proxy>
 ProxyPass / balancer://JAVA/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid scolonpathdelim=On
 
 ProxyPass / balancer:/glassfish 

</VirtualHost>